# How to filter hardcoded list via table in DB2?

Tags: sql, list, db2, filtering

I am new to DB2 and facing a problem right now.

I have a hardcoded list of identityNo's and a table which has a column called identityNo. I want to find the identityNo's such that they will be in the hardcoded list, but not in the any row of the table.

**Example:**

List: 1, 2, 3, 4

```
select count(*) from myTable where identityNo = 1 => 3

select count(*) from myTable where identityNo = 2 => 0

select count(*) from myTable where identityNo = 3 => 1

select count(*) from myTable where identityNo = 4 => 0
```

**Expected Result:** 2 and 4 (any format acceptable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4) MINUS SELECT identityNo FROM myTable
```

i.e.

```
create table myTable(identityNo int);
insert into myTable values (1),(3);
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4) MINUS SELECT identityNo FROM myTable;

1          
-----------
          4
          2

  2 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: **It says:** SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0104] Token MINUS was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET.

Comment: If you don't say what version of DB2 you are using, you might get an answer that only works on say Db2 LUW..   try the keyword `EXCEPT` instead of the `MINUS`  they are the same in LUW, Db2 for i might only support the latter

Answer (score 1):

In DB2, you can do:

```
select i.id, count(t.identityNo)
from (select 1 as id from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 3 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 4 from sysibm.sysdummy1 
     ) i left join
     mytable t
     on t.identityNo = i.id
group by i.id
order by i.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not practical for long lists, like I have.